# Why is TS complaining of type usage when a type entry is expected?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, typeerror, vuejs3

Consider the following code of a Vue3 component that receives an Array of Objects as a prop:

```
<script lang="ts">

interface CorveesI {
  What: string,
  Who: string,
  Debit: number
}

export default {
  name: 'Corvees',
  props: {
    corvees: {
      type: CorveesI[]
    }
  },
(...)
```

When compiling it, I have a warning on the line `type: CorveesI[]`:

```
TS2693: 'CorveesI' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I do not really know what to do with this, as **I am telling what type `corvees` is, give a type and I am told that it is a type but a value is expected.**

I read the documentation on [*Type Checks*](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#type-checks) but I do not see the bridge between my `interface` and the constructor.

Since I believe that my understanding of `interface` may be incorrect, I read the [TS doc for Object Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) but it loos very much like a type description (similar to `type` in Golang for instance). So I am lost.

Comment: You're exporting a _value_ - when the types are erased by the compiler, what's the value for props.corvees.type going to be?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import { PropType } from "vue";
...
corvees: {
  type: Array as PropType<CorveesI[]>
}
```

Reference: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props

Answer (score 3):

The `type` expected in [prop definitions](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#type-checks) are not TypeScript types (as all TS types are compiled away when TS compiler transforms your code to plain JS) but JS runtime types. So only types mention in the above linked docs are valid.

To properly type the prop in TS, you must use `PropType<>` - [Annotating props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props)

```
import { PropType } from "vue";
...
corvees: {
  type: Array as PropType<CorveesI[]>
}
```